# How to avoid providing path in the code in Java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have an Exe file created using Java Swing. I recently added a below code to open multiple session of an application at the same time. It works fine.

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\Auto\format.exe")

The application is used by different users and hence they are forced to save the application on the same path. If not, they would be able to open multiple sessions.

How do I avoid using path here on this code or Is there a better option for me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the path to the user, there is no way you could know it, do you?

Comment: This is exactly why you should not use absolute paths. Ever.

Comment: Since it's an .exe file, create a Windows short-cut that passes the "active directory" to your program, and place any other programs that it needs to run in that active directory. Or pass in the directory as a command line parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get rid of the path, when your `*.exe` file is in the same folder or subfolder of your Java program.

The only thing you need to care about is, that of your program is installed on somes computer, that you take the `*.exe` with you. You just could copy the files or you could create an installer (my suggestion).

Comment: To add to the "create an installer" - I'm assuming you mean to use a configuration file containing the path and to create that configuration via an installer.

Comment: It wasn't that what I meant, but it would be a way.

Comment: @DB Yes, If that's possible or if I can get rid of using absolute path...

Comment: Just make sure that the .exe file is always in the same directory as your Java program and you will be fine. Then you just need to call .exec("format.exe")

Comment: @AlexanderKaschta That worked!! Thank you very much.